# How is h-*value* bootstrap class not working after i set the value of parent?

Tags: html, css, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-4

I want these divs to be 250px. When i go into my Site.css file and write the second code below it works...

```html
<div class="container h-100" style="height:500px;">
    <div class="row row-no-gutters" style="height:500px;">
        <div class="col-sm-4 h-50 bg-success">.col</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 h-50 bg-success">.col</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 h-50 bg-success">.col</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.h-50{
    height:50%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`h-*` class has `!important` mark. Hence it will always take precedence over your inline styles.

So your container was styled as 100% height not 500px.

To fix it, you just take out the `h-100` off the container, and apply the inline height either on the container or the row:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="height: 500px;">
        <div class="col-sm-4 h-50 bg-success">.col</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 h-50 bg-success">.col</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 h-50 bg-success">.col</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/rkvztch0/3/

Comment: Oh i didn't mean to put that in here, it's still not working for me without this :(. It's some MVC nature problem but i don't know which.